# Nest can't resolve dependencies repository

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I do have the next application:
https://github.com/Aleonor1/barber-shop

Im getting the next error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BarberRepositoryImpl (?). Please make sure that the argument BarberRepository at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If BarberRepository is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If BarberRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing BarberRepository */ ]
  })
```

I dont know how to solve this, I tried to add the class in app module but it is not working. Help please

I tried to add the barber repository in AppModule and it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the import of `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Barber])` to create the provider injected by `@InjectRepository(Barber)`

Comment: I found the solution on the internet after a while... Thanks for the response!